# Efficient way to storage large lists in a file(s)

Tags: export, compression, storage

Let us assume that I need to storage in a file, or files, data with the following form

```
alist = 
  Table[Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2], {i, 1, 200}], {j, 1, 10000}];
blist = 
  Table[Table[{RandomReal[{0, 1}, 6], RandomReal[], 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, 6], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 6]}, {i, 1, 200}], {j, 
    1, 10000}];
clist = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000];
```

In a few seconds, Mathematica is able to create these lists.

However, when I try to export this data to a .txt file, using

```
Export["C:\\pathname\\abclists.txt", {alist, blist, clist}];
```

My computer starts to freeze, and I have to abort the evalutation. When I check the result, Mathematica has created a 600MB .txt file.

Is there a more efficient way to storage data in a file or files? I have no preference for the file type, as long as I can easily rebuild the original data, preserving the list levels.

Comment: Have you tried `DumpSave`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`ByteCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) will tell you to expect more than 1 GB:

```
ByteCount @ { alist, blist, clist }

(* 1 136 880 448 *)
```

**Compress**

I would thus try [`Compress`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compress.html):

```
cexpr = Compress @ { alist, blist, clist };
(* Export["pathname\\data.m", cexpr ]; *)
ByteCount @ cexpr

(* 437 359 280 *)
```

I am getting a 433 MB file (which roughly matches `ByteCount`). You can [`Uncompress`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Uncompress.html) the expression after loading.

**BinarySerialize**

Another possibility as of Version 11.1 or later is [`BinarySerialize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinarySerialize.html):

```
bexpr = BinarySerialize @ { alist, blist, clist };
ByteCount @ bexpr

(* 378 170 128 *)
```

So we are down to about 378 MB (the file is 312 MB on my computer). You can use [`BinaryDeserialize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryDeserialize.html) to get the original expression again (see below for explicit instructions for writing/reading binary data).

If we give the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Size"`

```
bexpr = BinarySerialize[ {alist,blist,clist}, PerformanceGoal -> "Size" ];
ByteCount @ bexpr

(* 327 494 245 *)
```

we are down to about 327 MB.

**Writing and Reading Binary Data**

The documentation tells you how to write/read binary data:

```
stream = OpenWrite[ "pathname\\data.mx", BinaryFormat -> True ];
BinaryWrite[ stream, bexpr ];
Close @ stream;
```

Reading the data:

```
data = BinaryDeserialize @ ByteArray @ BinaryReadList[ "pathname\\data.mx", "Byte" ];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To load the data, would we use ReadList or Import? If it's with import, could you show me how? The documentation talks about 'elements', but I don't know what they are, and how they relate to our compressed data.

I tried using ReadList, but I had to abort the evaluation...

Comment: Considering that the structure contains $4.2\times10^7$ fully random elements with 8 bytes each, I don't think you can do much better, even with an approach that stores the structure of the data more efficiently

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, that should indeed be mentioned:  The random data here are a "worst case" - but the problem still is a general one.

Comment: Thanks gwr. I've tried BinarySerialize, but Mathematica doesn't recognize it as a built-in function... Also, I've noticed that if we separate the file into 3, for each list, then the combined time for  import, export, compress, and uncompress are much lower in total...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. One has to play around with it. I added the information, that BinarySerialize is only available for Version 11.1 or later.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Old (OS and Mma version dependent!) "MX" format is also pretty fast and good for storing.

```
abcList = {alist, blist, clist};
ByteCount[abcList]
```

Out[2]= 1136880448

```
Export[
 FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
   "test.mx"}], abcList, "MX"];

FileByteCount[
 FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], "test.mx"}]]
```

Out[4]= 434116760

```
abcListRead = 
  Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
     "test.mx"}]];

ByteCount[abcListRead]
```

Out[6]= 1136880448